# Show Div above aside and main Content

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I would like to have the following Layout:
[image: Example Layout]

The Aside Content will display contain the Navigation Bar as well as an Option for the User and some other Links. When the User clicks on the User Icon, an Overlay should be shown. This is kind of working, but the Problem is that it is shown inside the aside Area and I didn't find a Solution until now to show it above the aside and main Content.

This is what I have until now for the HTML Part (Only Structure of the Layout without any Content):

```
<div className='App'>
    <aside
        className={'Left-Side-Menu'}
        id="Sidebar"
        <div>
            <Dropdown
                icon="fas fa-cog"
                text="Settings"/>
        </div>
    </aside>
    <main className='Main'>
        <!-- Content -->
    </main>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.App {
    min-height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
}

.Left-Side-Menu {
    bottom: 50px;
    height: 100%;
    margin-top: 0;
}

.Main {
    padding: 0.5rem;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Dropdown:

```
import React, {ReactNode, useRef, useState} from "react";
import useDetectOutsideClick from "@/hooks/useDetectOutsideClick";
import './Dropdown.sass';
import Icon from "@/components/ui/Icon/Icon";

interface IProps {
    icon?: string;
    badge?: string;
    customToggle?: any;
    contentData?: Array<object>;
    renderItems?: any;
    renderFooter?: any;
    children?: ReactNode;
    text?: string;
}

const Dropdown: React.FC<IProps> = ({
                                               icon,
                                               badge,
                                               customToggle,
                                               contentData,
                                               renderItems,
                                               renderFooter,
                                               children,
                                               text
                                           }) => {

    const dropdownRef = useRef(null);
    const [isVisible, setIsVisible] = useState(false);

    const handleDeactivate = () => {
        setIsVisible(false);
    }

    const handleActivate = () => {
        setIsVisible(true);
    }

    useDetectOutsideClick(dropdownRef, handleDeactivate);

    return (
        <div
            ref={dropdownRef}
            className="Dropdown">
            <button
                onClick={handleActivate}
                className="Dropdown--Toggle">
                {
                    icon ? <Icon iconName={icon}/> : ''
                }
                {
                    badge ? <span className="Dropdown--Toggle-Badge">{badge}</span> : ''
                }
                {
                    text ? <span className={`Dropdown--Toggle-Text ${badge ? '' : 'Text-Adjust'}`}>{text}</span> : null
                }
                {
                    customToggle !== undefined ? customToggle() : ''
                }

            </button>

            <div className="Dropdown-Container">
                <div
                    className={`Dropdown--Content ${isVisible ? 'Active' : ''}`}>
                    {
                        contentData !== undefined && renderItems !== undefined ?
                            contentData.map((item, index) => renderItems(item, index)) :
                            children !== undefined ? children : ''
                    }
                    {
                        renderFooter !== undefined ? (
                            <div className="Dropdown--Footer">
                                {renderFooter()}
                            </div>
                        ) : ''
                    }
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    );

}

export default Dropdown;
```